# Detecting problems in manifest with Manifest Merger

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

**Manifest Merging** tool was released to handle conflicts automatically when integrating app and library AAR manifests.

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/manifest-merge.html

However there is known problem that when you declare the same intent action for 2 or more broadcasts receivers, only one (picked randomly) receiver will respond when such action occurs. 
Most popular case is when trying to catch referrer: `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER`

and there are e.g. 2 receivers:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.myapp.ReceiverA"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.mylib.ReceiverB"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My question is whether it's possible to somehow **use ManifestMerger** to detect if there are 2 **receivers** with **conflicting intent filter action**:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

and prevent developer from building project until he fixes it.

Comment: "when you declare the same intent action for 2 or more broadcasts receivers, only one (picked randomly) receiver will respond when such action occurs" -- normally, they will both get it. In this case, receivers are really being used for a "narrowcast", where the sender is (presumably) using `queryIntentReceivers()` to identify a specific component to send the broadcast to. `priority` on the `<intent-filter>` might help more deterministically decide which gets it. You can't just ban duplicate receiver actions, as for normal broadcasts, it works fine.

Comment: FWIW, I filed [a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194616) to add some detection for this case, as I'm fairly certain it's not presently covered.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've been unable to find `queryIntentReceivers()`. Did you mean `queryBroadcaseReceivers()`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's `queryIntentActivities()` for activities and `queryIntentServices()` for services, and I was working from memory and thought that the names all had parallel construction.

Comment: You are actually right it's only for referrer receiver as referrer info is passed only to specific broadcast. I also don't think it's currently possible but wanted to confirm :) Thank you !